# how to resize an overlayed div depending on the img's size

Tags: html, css

I used this css to overlay the two elements, the image is underneath the overlayed texts:
I need to make sure that the overlay-ed layer should be resized automatically depending on the image's size to ensure a good UI of the elements .

```css
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Black see-through */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flow-root;
}

.underneath {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.h1 h3 {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="underneath">
    <img src="./overviewBanner.webp">
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <h1>
      <strong>Let's see what to do today</strong>
    </h1>
    <h3> Check below how to contribute</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How I'd do something like this is using inset: 0 on the overlay whilst adding postition: absolute to the overlay too and removing position: absolute; from the .underneath class. (Inset: 0 is basically shorthand for top:0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0.).

So:

```
.container { 
  max-width: fit-content;
}
.overlay { 
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}
```

If you need the image to bee 100% container width and potentially wider than the image's full width I'd use a background-image on the .underneath class instead of an img tag and give the .underneath div a set height and remove max-width: fit-content from the container.

```
.underneath {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 600px; 
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(./overviewBanner.webp);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach, with two different image-sizes, is below; in each case the CSS remains exactly the same. To achieve this we take advantage of CSS grid, placing both the `overlay` and the `underneath` in the same cell, and placing the `overlay` 'above' (between the `underneath` and the viewer) due to its later position in the DOM.

The code for this is below, with explanatory comments in the CSS; please note: I removed the use of `z-index` and `position: absolute`, as they aren't necessary to achieve the end-result:

```css
/* to allow for font-sizing across the page: */
:root {
  --fontBaseSize: 16px;
  --fontScale: 1;
}

/* a simple CSS reset to remove browser-default margins
   and padding, and specifying that all elements should
   be sized to include border-width and padding in their
   declared sizes; also sets the shared font-size, and
   font-family: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: calc(var(--fontBaseSize) * var(--fontScale));
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  /* using CSS grid: */
  display: grid;
  /* setting one column to take up all
     available space: */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  /* using margin-block (CSS logical property)
     to place a 1em margin both before and after
     the element on its block axis: */
  margin-block: 1em;
}

.underneath {
  /* positioning the element in the first row
     and first column of the grid: */
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
}

.overlay {
  /* setting background-color and color properties: */
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0.5);
  color: rgb(235 235 235 / 1);
  display: grid;
  /* positioning the element in the first row
     and first column of the grid: */
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  /* this places the grid-items in the center, on
     both inline and block axes: */
  place-content: center;
}

h1 {
  /* demonstrating the use of the --fontScale custom property,
     the font-size is calculated via the the CSS calc() function
     multiplying the --baseFontSize by the --fontScale; therefor
     changing the --fontScale property changes the  calculated
     result: */
  --fontScale: 2;
}

h3 {
  --fontScale: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="underneath">
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/400">
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <h1>
      <strong>Let's see what to do today</strong>
    </h1>
    <h3> Check below how to contribute</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="underneath">
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/950">
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <h1>
      <strong>Let's see what to do today</strong>
    </h1>
    <h3> Check below how to contribute</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fw6o9zqj/).

References:

- [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).
- [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color).
- [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties).
- [CSS Logical Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family).
- [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).
- [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`margin-block-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-end).
- [`margin-block-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-start).
- [`margin-inline-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline-end).
- [`margin-inline-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline-start).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`padding-block-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block-end).
- [`padding-block-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block-start).
- [`padding-inline-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-end).
- [`padding-inline-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline-start).
- `place-content`.